# How to check if static file caching is working in Apache built with ea4?

Tags: apache, caching, easyapache-4

I have installed `mod_file_cache` via **EasyApache 4 (Apache 2.4.39)** in `cpanel` (version 78) and it's enabled as well, is there any way to check if it's running or caching content at all via ssh command?

Comment: [How to list Apache enabled modules?](https://serverfault.com/questions/475173/how-to-list-apache-enabled-modules)

Comment: Thanks Dusan, it helped, but my question was more about if there was a command or something that to know if it's really caching or not.

Comment: First, are sure you really wanted `mod_file_cache` or maybe you need just [mod_cache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html) and [mod_cache_disk](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache_disk.html)?

Comment: OK I'm using mod_cache and mod_cache_disk now and it works perfectly. :)